# Calculating the absolute processing time of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

For the purpose of this question I am not interested in big-O calculations; as I understand, it is used to compare relatively between algorithms, whereas I want to have an estimation of absolute time taken to run an algorithm.

For example, I am using a vision algorithm that carries out approximately 2 million calculations/frame. The program runs on a core-i7 desktop. Then, how long will it take?

To compute this time duration, which cpu operation should I take as a worst case calculation (*,/,+,.. on floating point numbers, or something else)?

Comment: Depending on the specific moment that you run your program, this could have wildly different exact execution times. Finding exact time complexity is hard because there are so many factors that it could depend on.

Comment: This is too broad to be accurately answered.

Comment: You should implement said "vision algorithm", whatever that is, and then run it. You basically pull out your stop watch and press it when your program starts, and press it again when your program stops. Alternatively you could write a program to see how long your program will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, a meaningful answer is probably impossible.

First of all, a great deal will depend on how many of those operations can be executed in parallel. First let's consider the ideal case: you've optimized the code to execute in parallel perfectly. Each core is executing 4 instructions every clock cycle.

In this case, you're retiring 16 instructions per clock cycle, so you have 2 million/16 = 125000 clock cycles. At 4 GHz, that works out to 31.25 microseconds.

At the opposite extreme, let's assume the code is perfectly serial -- at most one instruction is retiring per clock cycle. For an even worse case, it might not only be serial, but heavily memory bound, so only one instruction is retiring every (say) hundred clock cycles (on average). In this case, you're looking at 50 milliseconds to execute the same number of instructions -- over 1000 times slower.

These are, of course, quite extreme examples -- a more typical case might be a cache miss ever couple dozen instructions, giving an average of, say, 1.8 instructions per clock cycle. With an average utilization of, perhaps, 2.5 cores you get an average of 4.5 instructions per clock cycle. That would give 444444 clock cycles, which works out to 111 microseconds (again, assuming 4 GHz).

Comment: @Mic and Jerry: thank you for the answers, at least I can picture clearer the scope of my question and have some hints if I might want to dig deeper to answer it

Comment: @Mr Jerry: I'm not using parallel/thread programming (no TBB,..), so mine falls to 2nd/3rd case. THanks so much for the numbers, so nice :)

Comment: @SonLe: Even without using threads, you can typically expect some instruction level parallelism -- assuming you've done little or nothing to enable instruction parallelism, the 1.8 might easily be in the right ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [floating point operations per second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) and calculate the worst case required flops of your algorithm. You can also time your algorithm with a specific (and sufficiently large) input size and use the time complexity analysis to estimate the execution time in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to somehow get a baseline of the execution time, because execution time can vary a lot depending on the architecture.

For example, a cache miss might eat up 300 CPU cycles whereas the same data access may eat up only 5 cycle if you have a cache hit. It can change a lot the running time on the long run if you add up all variables accesses.

So you have to get an idea of the execution time of your algorithm on specific input sizes. Then you match it with the expected complexity (Big-O complexity). You then deduce an approximate value for the leading constant, and you now have an approximation of the execution time for your algorithm on reasonable inputs.

By *reasonable*, I mean inputs for which you won't run into totally different behaviors such as swapping / paging (where you basically can't have much of an idea of the running time).